# Complete fields in web application test calling data from a mapping document in Python/Eclipse/DyDev

Tags: java, python, eclipse, selenium, pydev

Sorry if this is covered elsewhere, I have searched using as many ways I could think to word the question.

Anyway, I’m new to test automation and I’m using Eclipse, Python (via PyDev) with Selenium webdriver. Prior to this, I wrote some texts using Java and using Java I had my test scripts used alongside a separate Mapping Repository document (which had all the xpaths and IDs mapped), which I called in my test script using a public class and “extends” to the mapping repo which was called. This helped me keep the test script tidy and keep all fields mapped in one place.

Is there an equivalent in Python? (Sorry if that didn’t make sense). I have my Python test script which runs over one of my company websites, I use selemium webdriver to open the browser, I also use the element located functions, but would like to fill out the website fields calling the mapping document rather than clutter up my test script.

Apologies for how I worded that, I’m fairly new to all of this and writing scripts while learning python in parallel so it’s a bit of an “in at the deep end” scenario.

Edit: Code samples added:
The java looked like the below code (I’ve chopped two sections which hopefully demonstrate what I mean). And I’ve added the start of my Python code. So I suppose what I’m asking is the python equivalent of the below “public class OneRiskMotorBind extends MappingRepository{“ bit of code if that makes more sense?

Java Mapping Document:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class MappingRepository {

//*** login screen ***
    static String loginarea ="/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div";
    static String LogOnUsername = "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input";
    static String LogonPasswordbox = "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input";
    static String LoginscreenLoginbutton="/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span/span/span[1]";
    static String Maindrphdob= "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div";
    static String Gender = "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input";
    static String TitleList = "/html/body/div[6]/div";
```

Java Test Script

```
import java.io.File;
public class OneRiskMotorBind extends MappingRepository{

final static String CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "chromedriver-2.3.1.exe";
private static Random ran = null;
//private static final String ComboBox = null;
   private static String retry = null;
   static DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities;
   static WebDriver driver;
   static //initialise string objects
   String dbset = null;
   String RndSurname = null;
   static String retry2 = null;
   //Select the environment
   static String environment = "12";

    static String Brand = "Test";
    static String TitleList = "Mr";
    static String Gender = "M";
    static String Maindrphfirstname = "Test"; 
    static String Maindrphdob = "12091995";
    static String Maindrphaddyone = "127";
```

Example of current python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


class PortalLogin(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_portal_login(self):

    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()#new
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("App URL")
    driver.maximize_window()


    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email'))
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(element_present)
        print ("Page is ready!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    #time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
    email.send_keys("test@email.com")
```

Comment: Welcome, can you please add the Java code of yours and maybe also the one you tried for Python, even if it is not complete.

Comment: I've added this above now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get flagged for adding this as an answer, but I don't have the ability to comment yet. I'm having a hard time understanding what the question is... If you could, would you be able to phrase a specific 1 sentence question? or maybe a list of what your goals are?

Comment: OK, I'll try :) Looking at the above bit of code in the java test script, which pulls field info (xpath) from a separate mapping document I created, I would like to do the equivalent in my python test script.